# Executing command in many subfolders in windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I am in a folder with 24 subfolders. The subfolders are named Angle1, Angle2, ..., Angle24. In each of these subfolders, I want to perform this command:

```
Get-ChildItem PKA.dump -r | Sort-Object $_ | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Select -Index 19 } > output.txt
```

Is there a way to do this with Windows PowerShell?

Note, I do not want to perform command in subsubfolders.

This in not quite doing what I want:

```
Get-ChildItem/*/ PKA.dump -Recurse | Sort-Object $_ | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Select -Index 19 } > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

Create a PowerShell object in the Parent(i.e. `script.ps1` holding `Get-ChildItem PKA.dump -r | Sort-Object $_ | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Select -Index 19 } > output.txt`), and enable Unsigned execution with: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` from an Admin PowerShell

Copy and paste this into a batch file:

```
copy script.ps1 Angle1
cd Angle1
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle2
cd Angle2
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle3
cd Angle3
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle4
cd Angle4
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle5
cd Angle5
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle6
cd Angle6
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle7
cd Angle7
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle8
cd Angle8
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle9
cd Angle9
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle10
cd Angle10
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle11
cd Angle11
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle12
cd Angle12
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle13
cd Angle13
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle14
cd Angle14
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle15
cd Angle15
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle16
cd Angle16
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle17
cd Angle17
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle18
cd Angle18
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle19
cd Angle19
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle20
cd Angle20
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle21
cd Angle21
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle22
cd Angle22
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle23
cd Angle23
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
copy script.ps1 Angle24
cd Angle24
powershell .\script.ps1
del script.ps1
cd ..
exit
```

Save and run that script as an admin.

For example: `script.bat` Right Click, `Run as Administrator`

Comment: that gives me a lot of errors. something like, the script.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program

Comment: ooh I knew I forgot something, gimme a sec

Comment: a lot of errors saying the system could not find the path specified also

Comment: even with your edit i still get the same errors

Comment: you need script.ps1 to have `Get-ChildItem PKA.dump -r | Sort-Object $_ | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_ | Select -Index 19 } > output.txt` inside it

Comment: i do have that inside it

Comment: It looks like it is looking in C:/script and not in my current directory. could that be the issue?

Comment: ok, can you paste the exact text that PS is outputting on error? Shift Right Click, and select Command Prompt, then type `script.bat >log.txt`

Comment: Yes, both scripts need to be in the parent folder of Angle1 through Angle24

Comment: i got it to work, not sure what changed. but it worked! do you know if there is a way to take the 9th column from all of these output.txt files and create a new file called total.txt with each column separated by some type of delimiter?

Comment: No, I know a lot about CMD, but I'm actively a linux dev

Comment: @JacksonHart - If that helped, mind marking it as the answer?